# Why is Java giving me a ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, sql, api, maven

I've got a Maven project running and when I try and run a GET call it prints a ClassNotFound exception to the console and then gives me a null result on the page. I have a dynamic web project that I copied/pasted the code from and it works fine on that. I have no idea how to debug it because it looks like it should work.

Here's the error:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Jul/2013:21:35:19 +0000] "GET /parties HTTP/1.1" 200 87 163 163
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [18/Jul/2013:21:35:19 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1329 9 9
```

And here's the code where it happens:

```
    package core;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DBConnection {

    private Connection con;
    private static Statement statement;
    private static ResultSet resultSet;
    public  static DBConnection connection;
    private static ResultSetMetaData meta;
    private static HashMap<String,Party> map;

    public Party party;

    private DBConnection()
    {
        try 
        {
            map = new HashMap<String,Party>();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://atom3.cisco.com:3306/asdf", "asdf",
                    "asdf");
            statement = con.createStatement();
            readData();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("Error: "+e);
        }
    }
    public void readData()
    {
        try
        {
            map.clear();
            String query = "(SELECT * FROM PureServlet)";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
            String columnName, value, partyName;
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                partyName = resultSet.getString("PARTY_NAME");
                map.put(partyName, new Party()); //this is the map that keeps track of all parties
                party = map.get(partyName);
                for(int j=1;j<=meta.getColumnCount();j++) //necessary to start at j=1 because of MySQL index starting at 1
                {
                    columnName = meta.getColumnLabel(j);
                    value = resultSet.getString(columnName);
                    party.getPartyInfo().put(columnName, value); //this is the hashmap within the party that keeps 
                    //track of the individual values. The column Name = label, value is the value
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public static HashMap<String,Party> getPartyCollection()
    {
        if(connection == null)
        {
            connection = new DBConnection();
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to add the dependency. Coulda sworn I'd added it before, must've accidentally deleted it.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
```

Comment: This is what I edited to my answer, I didn't see your answer while editing :)

Answer (score 0):

JAR file (ojdbc6.jar) is missing in lib directory.
Download and put it in lib directory and try again.